# Java to Python - Pass RSA Public Key into Function

Tags: python, java, rsa, public-key-encryption, public-key

I am trying to convert an encryption algorithm that uses RSA Encryption from Java to Python.

I have been working on it for a week and have made some progress but I have stuck on converting this Java specific function below.

```
    private static String encryptMessage(String randomToken, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(randomToken.getBytes()));
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to pass the public key which is in this format in Java into a python data type to be passed into the function.

```
{public=Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  params: null
  modulus: 5438....
  public exponent:12237}
```

Once I am able to pass the key in the correct format. What are the python equivalent calls within the function?

Some assistance and Guidance would be very much helpful.

Comment: PyCryptoDome e.g. is been able to build a RSA public key using modulus and exponent: https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html#Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.construct

Comment: Most major Python libraries support the construction of an RSA key based on its components, e.g. also the [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPublicNumbers) library, so you are not limited to a specific library.

Comment: And the important parts of the public key are what you have there, the bits, the bits, the modulus, and the exponent.  Though I confess, that's not an exponent I've seen before.  Usually, its 3 or t or 65537.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments!! they were extremely helpful! I was able to use https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html#Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.construct method to create the correct public key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the pycryptodome library I was able to construct the correct public key using the modulus and exponent.

https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html#Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.construct